# Turn semicolon separated string into JSON array in MySQL

Tags: mysql, arrays, string, function

I need to create a function that will turn this data: "test1@test.com;test2@test.com" into JSON like string: "["test1@test.com", "test2@test.com"]".

In MySQL function...
Any ideas?

Comment: Just to note - this isn't really what MySQL is for.

Comment: CONCAT() and REPLACE() - nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> SET @value := '"test1@test.com;test2@test.com"';
> SELECT @value, CONCAT('"[', REPLACE(@value, ';', '", "'), ']"');
> ```
>
> | @value | CONCAT('"[', REPLACE(@value, ';', '", "'), ']"') |
> | --- | --- |
> | "test1@test.com;test2@test.com" | "["test1@test.com", "test2@test.com"]" |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dd1aed174f905b3350a7da594702fdfe)*

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Akina! Further question :) -
if I use this code: 
`SET @value := client.email
SELECT @value, CONCAT('"[', REPLACE(@value, ';', '", "'), ']"');`
will it change all client.email's?

Comment: @kg Select can change nothing. Update needed. `UPDATE client SET email = CONCAT('"[', REPLACE(email, ';', '", "'), ']"');`